# How can i add multiple shipping and billing addresses in Magento2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

In magento REST API - I am getting only one shipping and billing addresses. but I want to add more than one shipping and billing addresses. Is there any way to do so?

And I want to all the list of addresses of user can I get using REST API?

Comment: what is the REST API call you are using?

Comment: http://www.ulr.com/rest/V1/customers/me

 {
          
          
            "region": {
                "region_code": "test",
                "region": "test",
                "region_id": 0
            },
            "region_id": 0,
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "test"
            ],
            "company": "test",
            "telephone": "test",
            "postcode": "53000",
            "city": "test",
            "firstname": "test",
            "lastname": "test"
        }
i am sending this body formate to add address